# Launch all the await task at the same time in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am learning xamarin Async,

I have a function that translate many sentences asynchronously.

I would like to change my function in order to launch all the await at the same time in App.xml.cs because some translations are not finished and I am redirected in MainPage

Here my fuction with all the await:

```
public async Task SetLeafLanguage() 
{
        var phoneLanguage = "fr";// CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

        // transversal
        var WarningConnexionText = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the first text", phoneLanguage);

        // Test page 
        var NumberOfWords = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);


        var ExerciceTitle = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

        var AnswerPlaceHolder = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

        var LabelNumberOfWordToTranslate = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

        // parameter labels
        var AboutUstext = await MicosoftTranslater.TranslateText("this the second text", phoneLanguage);

}


public async Task GetUserOnData()
{
    await SetLeafLanguage();
    MainPage = new MainPage();
}

public App ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetUserOnData();
}
```

Comment: Read about Task.WhenAll() and factor that into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. DO NOT AWAIT.

Colellect the threads, and then possibly await them once all the services have started. NOTHING forces you to await the task returned right in the same line.

Comment: I am redirected to the MainPage without all the transalation finished

Comment: Then you NEVER await. This is not what I said. First start all the tasks, THEN await all the tasks.